# Why does the expression $\frac {x(10^x-1)}{9}$ yield "$x$, repeated $x$ times" (eg, $5\to 55555$)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

What is the logic behind this particular expression?

$$ \frac {x(10^x-1)}{9} $$

Basically, if one puts any number $x$ into the expression above, you get the number $x$, repeated $x$ times. Case in point: `5` would be `55555`, etc.

Why does this work the way it does? Is it possible to simplify this at all and get the same result?

Comment: I see no equation...

Comment: Still don't see it...I do see an expression

Comment: @6005 Technically, $ \frac {x(10^x-1)}{9} $ is an expression but is not an equation. Someone is having some fun by being pedantic. (FWIW, I got a chuckle out of this too.)

Comment: @Christian The formula was apparently copied incorrectly from somewhere. The latest edit makes it work (though I'm not sure it's always OK to "fix" an OP's formulas in this way.)

Comment: @DavidK I suspected that the current version was the intended formula but I figured I would ask just in case something else was meant... I removed my comment since it is resolved!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Just FYI, you should not make edits like this to posts, namely edits that change the original meaning of the question. This should possibly be rolled back, but now that the answers address the new question it's probably all right in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you originally wrote, $x \cdot \frac{10^{x-1}}{9}$, doesn't work. For example for $x = 5$ you get
$$
5 \cdot \frac{10^4}{9} = 5555.555555555\ldots
$$
which isn't even an integer.

The correct equation (which is now updated in the OP) is
$$
x \cdot \frac{10^{x} - 1}{9} \tag{1}
$$
Plugging in $x = 5$ we get $55555$, which is what you want. This also works for anything from $x = 1$ to $x = 9$, but it doesn't work for numbers larger with more than one digit. For example, if we plug in $12$ we get
$$
12 \cdot \frac{10^{12} - 1}{9} = 1\,333\,333\,333\,332.
$$

### How does it work?

The ${10^x - 1}$ gives you a list of $x$ 9's: for example, $10^5 - 1$ is one less than $100000$, which is $99999$, $5$ 9's.
Then dividing by $9$, we get a list of $x$ 1's: $\frac{99999}{9} = 11111$ if $x = 5$. Finally, multiplying by $x$ (*if* $x$ is only a single digit) we get a list of $x$ $x$'s.

Comment: Good catch on the case $x>9$. And first answer (one second earlier than the second answer).

Answer (score 4):

For any integer $x$ in the range $[1,9]$ we have
$$ 10^x-1 = \underbrace{99\ldots99}_{x \text{ times}}\tag{1}$$
hence
$$ \frac{10^x-1}{9} = \underbrace{11\ldots11}_{x \text{ times}}\tag{2}$$
and:
$$ x\cdot\frac{10^x-1}{9} =  \underbrace{xx\ldots xx}_{x \text{ times}}.\tag{3}$$